# Getting SDL_ttf to play nice with SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-ttf

I've recently started migrating from using SDL (1.2.15) to SDL2 (2.0.0), and had previously depended on using the extension library SDL_ttf (2.0.11) to render fonts. When I try to use the same text library I used with version one SDL with SDL2 (admittedly not yet officially released), it compiles just fine. When I run the executable, though (I'm using VS2012 for Desktop at the moment), I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x6C7D8C24 (SDL2.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000045.
```

From what I can gather, this is due to the following bits of code. I have created a Window class to encapsulate some usual SDL functions:

window.cpp:

```
SDL_Texture* Window::RenderText(const std::string &message, const std::string &fontFile, SDL_Color color, int fontSize){
//Open the font
TTF_Font *font = nullptr;
font = TTF_OpenFont(fontFile.c_str(), fontSize);
if (font == nullptr)
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load font: " + fontFile + TTF_GetError());

//Render the message to an SDL_Surface, as that's what TTF_RenderText_X returns
SDL_Surface *surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, message.c_str(), color);
SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(mRenderer.get(), surf);
//Clean up unneeded stuff
SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
TTF_CloseFont(font);

return texture;
}
```

It's getting tripped up by the

```
SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(mRenderer.get(), surf);
```

line, where the created SDL_Surface is incompatible with SDL2's definition of Surfaces, and so when it tries to convert the SDL_Surface into an SDL_Texture, it flips out.

I don't think I'm the only one to have run into this issue, so is there a workaround/updated version of SDL_ttf that fixes this, or should I hold off on moving to SDL2 until I can get fonts working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check out the [Mercurial Repository](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL_ttf/) for SDL_TTF?  It seems to have been updated for `SDL2`, it would definitely be worth it to synch the latest code and build that.